# Purpose of designing overwritten by checkout error

Tags: git

I believe the following error rings the bell if you ever use Git to do version control:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
> test.txt
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> Aborting

And I know you can either commit the change or stash them before you checkout another branch to solve this issue.

However, I wonder why this mechanism is designed. What's going on behind the scene if I do this? In other words, what is the potential mistake would happen here or does this action just confuse Git?

Comment: "Why"? To avoid deleting your changes before they've been saved in the repository, so you can retrieve them without having to rewrite them from memory.

Comment: I think the answer to "why" might go something like this: They (Git creators) didn't want to require manual intervention in most commands by adding an "Are you sure?". And since (most) humans make mistakes, to avoid tears, the decision was made to error out, and provide a force option if you don't care if you're blowing away changes. (Since blowing away changes and then warning that it happened isn't very useful!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is not confused but aware that it would proceed with a destructive action. This mechanism is designed to not make you loose your (uncommitted/unstaged) local changes due to accidentally checking out files which would overwrite changed ones.

If you are absolutely sure of what you are doing, you can use the `-f` or `--force` flag which tells Git to proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This will overwrite the files and does not show a warning.